# Difficulty in partial update in DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, patch, put

I am learning Django and DRF, I am having issues updating the field `expire_on`. And there also I have to put the logic to prevent to put the value of `expore_on` no greater than 7 days from `created_on`. I am having trouble figuring out how to update the same and write the above logic.

I have tried:

1. [update function in DRF viewset.Viewset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68296478/11073827)
2. [Django Rest Framework not showing form fields for PATCH/PUT request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65816202/11073827)
3. [Django REST Framework doesn't display value in PUT form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47654662/11073827)
4. [Django form fields not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38333584/11073827)

**Models**

```
class Url_data(models.Model):
    uri_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    actual_url = models.URLField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, editable=False, auto_now=False)
    expire_on = models.DateTimeField()
    short_url = models.URLField(max_length=200, editable=False)
    clicks = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(
        default=0, editable=True, blank=True)
```

**Serializer**

```
class Url_dataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Url_data
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['short_url', 'created_on', 'clicks']

class ExpireDateUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Url_data
        fields = ('expire_on', )
```

**View**

```
class UrlList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Url_data.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class = Url_dataSerializer


class UrlDetail(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Url_data.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class = Url_dataSerializer


class ExpireDateUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Url_data.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class = ExpireDateUpdateSerializer
```

**URls (in-app)**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", index, name="home"),
    path("urls/", UrlList.as_view()),
    path("urls/<int:pk>/", UrlDetail.as_view()),
    path("urls/<int:pk>/", ExpireDateUpdate.as_view()),
]
```

**Error**

```
405
Undocumented
Error: Method Not Allowed

**Response body**
{
  "detail": "Method \"PATCH\" not allowed."
}

**Response headers**
 access-control-allow-origin: * 
 allow: GET,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS 
 content-length: 42 
 content-type: application/json 
 cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin 
 date: Fri,07 Jan 2022 22:19:09 GMT 
 referrer-policy: same-origin 
 server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.10 
 vary: Accept,Origin 
 x-content-type-options: nosniff 
 x-frame-options: DENY
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can not see which url you hit when you get this error. So, are you sure you make the rewuest to the correct url and it's update view?

Comment: here ate the URLs, I updated!
Please Suggest.

Comment: Use different urls for each view. That could not work that way.

Comment: path("urls/<int:pk>/", ExpireDateUpdate.as_view()) never get hit , due to the url  path("urls/<int:pk>/", UrlDetail.as_view()),

Comment: generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView   doesn't support  PATCH method. Your calls to url "   urls/<int:pk>/" always use UrlDetail,  To make it work use a different class in UrlDetail which support  update.

Comment: Use viewset instead of define each view  for   each method